# Flutter extract additional values from stream?

Tags: flutter, dart

I followed some tutorial about streams and am able to map a list of objects

```
return streamedRest.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(json.decoder).map((data) => data['results']).expand((data) => (data as List)).map((data) {
    return Item.fromJSON(data);
  });
```

But right now I would like to extract other variables like count/next/previous

```
{
    "count": 88,
    "next": "/items/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {...}
        ]
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to separate out the other values without causing the stream listen to fail.

Comment: so it seems you need another class keeping your count/next/previous amd a list of `Item`s - btw tried some online stuff like: https://app.quicktype.io/?

Comment: I know how to manipulate json, just really not clear how streams work. If there was a way to strip out data['next'] without it throwing the stream has already been listened to error I would be good to go.

Comment: so parse all the data coming from your stream (not only `data['results']`) and you will have access to your `count/next/previous` fields

Comment: I'm not sure how to. I can't assign the other fields to another variable inside the ```map((data) => data['results'])``` function and using ```forEach((data){ data['next'] })``` to assign the other values to external variables results in it refusing to compile.

Comment: simply remove that `map((data) => data['results'])` - this way you will be able to access all the data, not only `results`

Comment: Removing that line results in ```type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' ```